# Return the third to last elements of given list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am new in using Prolog, I want to write a program that compute the third to last element of a given list.
for instance

```
ThirdLast ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5] , Ans).
```

will give me:

```
Ans = [3, 4, 5]
```

I did this but is not working

```
len([],0). 
len([_|T],N)  :-  len(T,X),  N  is  X+1.
ThirdLast([ ],0)
ThirdLast([H|L1], X):-(len(L1,N)==2), X is H.
ThirdLast ([H|L1],X):-(len(L1,N)>2),ThirdLast (L1,X).
```

any ideas?

Comment: The terminology threw me. *Third to last* element would be `3` in this case. You really mean, *third **through** last element**s*** or *all but the first two elements*.

Comment: Lots of syntax errors (almost a dozen) and those errors sure are not alone! I would take a step back, dump the crap, go back to square one and take a fresh start.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple rule that ignores the first two elements:

```
tail3([_,_|T], T).
```

The first two elements get unified with `_`, and get thrown away. The rest of the list unifies with `T`, which is the result that we want to produce.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Nt34uQ)

Comment: we should consider any length of the list, so if I have [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] the result will be [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: @Imaginary That's much simpler! Please see the edit.